# KeyError: 'HTTP_ACCESS_TOKEN' : Flask with gevent WSGIServer

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I am trying to take my Flask application to production with [gevent](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#gevent) `WSGIServer`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    app_host = "0.0.0.0"
    app_port = "8080"
    #app.run(host=app_host, port=app_port, debug=False)

    http_server = WSGIServer((app_host, app_port), app)
    logging.info("Starting the App server")
    http_server.serve_forever()
```

I am running the app server with `gevent WSGIServer`. Whenever I am trying to fetch any data like

```
token = request.headers["access_token"]
```

Receiving the following error

```
File "app.py", line 62, in post
token = request.headers["access_token"]
File "/home/shravan40/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 1463, in __getitem__
return _unicodify_header_value(self.environ["HTTP_" + key])
KeyError: 'HTTP_ACCESS_TOKEN'
2020-08-03T18:01:31Z {'REMOTE_ADDR': '::ffff:127.0.0.1', 'REMOTE_PORT': '55088', 'HTTP_HOST': '127.0.0.1:8080', (hidden keys: 26)} failed with KeyError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pywsgi` has something called `SecureEnviron`. This is intended to keep potentially sensitive information like HTTP authorization and cookies from being inadvertently printed or logged.

One can read more at the [official documentation](https://www.gevent.org/api/gevent.pywsgi.html)

Since I was passing `access_token` as key in the headers and trying to access the same from the code, it was raising `KeyError: 'HTTP_ACCESS_TOKEN'` because wasn't part of `whitelist_keys`.

I used `Authorization` as header key and it worked like charm. The same can be done by adding `access_token` into the `whitelist_keys`.

Answer (score 0):

Not only headers like ACCESS_TOKEN, even arbitrary header names have this problem: A header like

```
header = {'MY_DEAR_RAJA' : '3AB690CDF3B'}
```

raised an error at the server, specifically in the line:

site-packages\werkzeug\datastructures.py", in **getitem**  return *unicodify_header_value(self.environ["HTTP*" + key])

I found that my use of underscores in the key name was the problem. When I changed them to hyphens it fixed the issue:

```
header = {'MY-DEAR-RAJA' : '3AB690CDF3B'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible problem could arise from how you are trying to access the header token.

If you are attempting to access the dictionary by using the keys directly, once the value is not present, it would raise a KeyError. Alternatively, you can access the dictionary using the get method. The non-existence of the value would not throw an error.

So, instead of using:

```
client_token = request.headers['access_token']
```

Use:

```
client_token = request.headers.get('access_token')
```

This modification ensures that if 'access_token' is not present in the headers, it won't raise a KeyError, and client_token will be assigned None by default. You can also provide a default value as the second argument to get if you want a specific value when the key is not found.